# User Custom environments in Angular

Tags: angular, environment-variables

In our angular project we have an environment.ts and environment.prod.ts

What I would like is to also have a environment.user.ts
Which would overide only variables if they are configured so testers/developers can more easily overide some configs personally.

I wonder if there is a generic pattern for this maybe by library import or a handy common way to do it.
Or perhaps do all people reinvent the wheel over and over

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can specify other build configurations in angular.json. It should be fairly obvious how if you look at the existing ones in there.

```json
{
  "projects": {
    "<project>": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "user": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.user.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "configurations": {
            "user": {
              "browserTarget": "<project>:build:user"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Documentation here: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#alternate-build-configurations